Can GeoTools parse GML geodetic shapes?
I am trying to parse different GML definitions, according to the geodetic shapes defined in RFC-5491. Points and polygons are parsed OK with GeoTools parser:
    Configuration configuration = new GMLConfiguration();
    Parser parser = new Parser(configuration);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(gmlString);
    Geometry fc = (Geometry) parser.parse(sr);

However, when it comes to Circle, Ellipse, Ellipsoid or ArcBan i.e:
<gs:Circle srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326" 
xmlns:gs="http://www.opengis.net/pidflo/1.0" 
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <gml:pos>42.5463 -73.2512</gml:pos>
    <gml:radius uom="urn:ogc:def:uom:EPSG::9001">850.24</gml:radius>
</gs:Circle>

I cannot parse this definition and I am getting this error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for Circle: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of points in LineString (found 1 - must be 0 or >= 2)

    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.ParseExecutor.visit(ParseExecutor.java:153)
    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.BindingWalker$BindingExecutionChain.execute(BindingWalker.java:218)
    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.BindingWalker.walk(BindingWalker.java:184)
    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.ElementHandlerImpl.endElement(ElementHandlerImpl.java:233)
    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.ParserHandler.endElement(ParserHandler.java:798)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:618)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1728)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2899)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:542)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:889)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:825)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1224)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:637)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:326)
    at org.geotools.xsd.Parser.parse(Parser.java:183)
    at org.geotools.xsd.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
    at com.example.jaxbdemo1.TestGeotools.testParse(TestGeotools.java:218)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of points in LineString (found 1 - must be 0 or >= 2)
    at org.locationtech.jts.geom.LineString.init(LineString.java:89)
    at org.locationtech.jts.geom.LineString.<init>(LineString.java:79)
    at org.locationtech.jts.geom.GeometryFactory.createLineString(GeometryFactory.java:621)
    at org.geotools.gml3.bindings.GML3ParsingUtils.line(GML3ParsingUtils.java:141)
    at org.geotools.gml3.bindings.GML3ParsingUtils.lineString(GML3ParsingUtils.java:118)
    at org.geotools.gml3.bindings.ArcStringTypeBinding.parse(ArcStringTypeBinding.java:140)
    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.ParseExecutor.visit(ParseExecutor.java:144)
    ... 22 more

Can GeoTools parse get this type of GML definitions? Or I am just missing something?

The error seems clear enough, no GeoTools can't parse your gml

you can use the GDAL Java bindings API

GeoTools can parse GML3 Circles and Curves (ArcStrings) but it doesn't seem to be able to handle circles defined by a centre and radius as you are trying to read. If you want to add this functionality I think you need to look at CircleTypeBinding and probably ArcStringBindingType. Please see the contribution guidelines to see how to help.
